# Split CSV file on comma, but both comma and the double quotes may occur inside a colum

Tags: regex, csv

I'm having a problem with a dataset from a very old system that I'm trying to import into a SQL database. In theory, it's a comma separated CSV file, however, there are multiple "traps" that I'm not fully able to solve.  If a column contains either space, double-quote or comma, it will be wrapped with double-quotes.

Here are some examples columns and lines (In total there is 54 columns, but most of them are just digits and easy to handle);

`129.00,"Some "Thing",55456`  <-- No problem to handle

`12.95,"Some Text 0,50",5131` <--- Comma inside double-quotes surrounded by numbers that might appear elsewhere in the dataset

`0.00,"Some Text" with ending",52787` <-- Double-quotes inside double quotes

`0.00,"Some. Text 2,-",52787`  <-- Comma inside double-quotes

`10.99,"Some Text 0,",00`  <-- Comma, double-quotes and comma again.

`5,78,"Some Text",-85.00` <- text followed by negative value

I have tweaked two commonly used regexes I found on this forum, but I'm not able to get any of them to work on all scenarios;

`,(?!-"|\d{2}")(?=(?:[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`   <-- Works on everything except Comma, double-quotes and comma again.

`,(?!-")(?=(?:[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` <-- Works on everything except for Comma inside double-quotes surrounded by numbers that might appear elsewhere in the dataset

Some help here would be much apricated! :)

Comment: The data you show is invalid: double quotes inside a field should be escaped with another double quote, like: `129.00,"Some ""Thing",55456`. Are you sure this isn't the case? (or do you have control over the creation of the csv?)

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunately the case. I'm aware that this is in an invalid format, but there is absolutely nothing I can do about it. It's data from a very old system, stored in files with the format I posted above, there is no database I can grab the data from an export them in a valid format :/

Comment: I understand that you'd would a regex as simple as possible, but have you considered simply matching all 54 columns with 1 giant regex? Since most of the columns are easily matchable you should be able to separate out the crazy ones which might make it easier?